# Turning specific rows into columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a little odd request. Turn a number of rows into columns.
My data looks like this:

| Software | Count | Install Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QWE | 1 | INSTALLED |
| ASD | 54 | INSTALLED |
| ASD | 3 | PENDINGINSTALL |
| ASD | 3 | FAILED |

But I would love for it to look like this:

| Software | INSTALLED | PENDINGINSTALL | FAILED | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QWE | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| ASD | 54 | 3 | 3 | 60 |

Is that possible just with a Query or do I need to use Reporting?

Comment: read up on PIVOT

Comment: Looks like a variation of the classic pivoting problem. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: *I have a little odd request*, no you actually have a *very* common requirement, it's called pivoting - search for that.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you can do this using Pivot, though Reporting Services can do it more easily using a Matrix. If you go the Pivot route, if you have a few fixed "Initial Status" values it's pretty easy, though if your list of status values must vary it becomes dynamic SQL and it's more complicated. Check out Pivot and/or Matrix in SSRS, and if you're still stuck update your question with info about your DBMS and the possible values of STATUS

Comment: I'll read up on pivot. 

I knew there had to be a way. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Your rude comment is on a question from many months back and adds nothing to the comments that precede it. It may be time to take a break from stackoverflow.